# UIPageViewController rotation weirdness

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I've added a UIPageViewController to my app to act as a manual for the app. When the user pops it up it shows one page in portrait and two in landscape with the spine in the middle. Since I have about 100 pages, there is a sibling view UICollectionView page selector view above it to allow jumping to a page quickly. Both the UIPageViewController and the UICollectionView sit on a backing view that contains them both.

The problem I am having with the UIPageViewController is that when the views are first rotated they seem to constrain themselves to the short dimension of the original layout. So, if it first appears in portrait, then when rotating to landscape the width of the two pages is the same as the old portrait width. Likewise, if it first appears landscape with two pages, rotating to portrait has the correct width, but the height is the height of the initial landscape height. This is consistent on any device.

When I create my content views they are all the size I desire, but for some reason they seem to be transformed by some component of UIPageViewController and I'm not grasping why it is only doing one of the two dimensions and why it is always the "short side" that is the problem.

This is one of those kinds of problem that makes me feel a bit nutty, any ideas on how I might debug it if it isn't some trivial misconfiguration?

Comment: I've taken some time off to work on other parts of the app and am just now getting back to this. Taking a fresh look at my content's loadView, the size is set once. It seems that perhaps the UIPageViewController is buffering the first size for the content view that it receives and adjusting things proportionally depending on the rotation. There's still something odd going on here that I haven't grasped. I'm going to try to brute force the size of the content each time it gets changed and see if that solves the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it after a long period of debugging. The critical hint was seeing that the spine is set to the correct mid for the width of the view BEFORE the rotation for portrait to landscape. The solution was to reset the frame of the view to the new size given the orientation in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation.

I calculate the new size before I call an animation block that uses the duration passed into the method, then inside the block I have:

```
  pageViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
```

When the page is rotated the view holding the content pages is shifted to the correct size and the spine is place correctly and the content fills the given area. I suppose that I ran into the problem because the complexity of the views required me to take over so many defaults, but this one was left hanging.

Comment: Where do you get that `newFrame` ?

Comment: It has been nearly three years and I no longer have the code in mind and cannot locate it. I believe that it was either passed to the method or else I calculated it based on the device's size. I'd no longer do it this way as we now have autolayout and a constraint system that allow us to avoid many of these kinds of issues.